# how to set drawableleft image from url with picasso library?

Tags: picasso

I need to load an image at `drawableLeft` from url. Is this possible?

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt_check_opportunity"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"                        
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_yellow_24dp"                        
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox_opportunity"
     android:text="@string/opportunity"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_large_size"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Picasso `Target`, load the image from the URL into the target and call `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` on the TextView with the `Bitmap` from the `onBitmapLoaded` callback of Picasso Target.

You need to also keep in mind that the Picasso Targets are [weakly referenced](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/83) so you need to be careful and keep strong references to your target.

I have implemented a widget called [PicassoTargetableTextView](https://gist.github.com/prashand/8b4223c7f96c7d5e300655c82f731b9c) that does all of that. You can use the `PicassoTargetableTextView.load(left, top, right, bottom)` to load drawables into the TextView at runtime.